# PHP get id of submit button

Tags: php, html

I am trying to determine which bus has been picked for a reservation but unfortunately, I am not able to get the id properly

```
  $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Departure WHERE RouteId = 3");

  $sql->execute();

  while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $row['DepDate'];
    echo "</td><td>75</td><td>";
    echo $row['Seats'];

    echo"</td><td> <input type='hidden' name='action' value='".$row['DepId']."' /><input id='";
    echo $row['DepId'];
    echo "' type='submit' name='submit' value='Pick'></td></tr>";   
  }
```

This code creates a table with the the busses from RouteId 3
For whatever reason, no matter which button I click, only the value of the last one gets set when I call $_POST['action']

Comment: `Id` values are never passed to server. Either use some js or add another hidden field to a form.

Comment: I added a hidden field, however, the value passed is always the latter one, never the one I chose.

Comment: This means that you have several fields with the same name on your form. And the last field is the passed result. Either create different form for each field or use `[]` for name: `name="action[]"`

Comment: Usign multiple forms sounds like a simple solution, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Above case instead of getting Identifying bus with which Submit button is clicked you can create multiple forms in PHP Loop and pass hidden value to identify which Bus is selected.

Eg.

```
 ...
    $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Departure WHERE RouteId = 3");

      $sql->execute();

      while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
      {
     ?>
     <tr>
    <form action="selectBus.php">
      <td><?php echo $row['DepDate']; ?></td>
      <td>75</td><td><?php echo $row['Seats']; ?></td>
     <td><input name='action' type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['DepId'];?>"/> 
     <input type="submit" value="select" /></td>
     </form>
     </tr>
    <?php
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: This code snippet helped me alot, thank you very much!